# Python numpy indexing confusion

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new in `python`, I was looking into a code which is similar to as follows,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones([1,1,5,5], dtype='int64')
b = np.ones([11], dtype='float64')
x = b[a]
print (x.shape)
# (1, 1, 5, 5)
```

I looked into the python `numpy` documentation I didn't find anything related to such case. I'm not sure what's going on here and I don't know where to look.

**Edit**
The actual code

```
def gausslabel(length=180, stride=2):
    gaussian_pdf = signal.gaussian(length+1, 3)
    label = np.reshape(np.arange(stride/2, length, stride), [1,1,-1,1])
    y = np.reshape(np.arange(stride/2, length, stride), [1,1,1,-1])
    delta = np.array(np.abs(label - y), dtype=int)
    delta = np.minimum(delta, length-delta)+length/2
    return gaussian_pdf[delta]
```

Comment: You are using ndarray Indexing which changes the array output. Check documentation [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

Comment: @SandeepKadapa what do you mean the array it self? Because in this case neither `a` nor `b` are changed.

Comment: @Dan It changes the output of array. Similar example was given with link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this code is trying to demonstrate that if you index an array with an array, the result is an array with the same shape as the indexing array (in this case `a`) and not the indexed array (i.e. `b`)

But it's confusing because `b` is full of `1`s. Rather try this with a `b` full of different numbers:

```
>> a = np.ones([1,1,5,5], dtype='int64')
>> b = np.arange(11) + 3
array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
>>> b[a]
array([[[[4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
         [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
         [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
         [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
         [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]]])
```

because `a` is an array of `1`s, the only element of `b` that is indexed is `b[1]` which equals `4`. The shape of the result though is the shape of `a`, the array used as the index.

Comment: I think I am clear now. The output shape actually made it confusing. Thanks.